# unable to load cpp dll.The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

Tags: asp.net

i am using cpp dll in my application.
and in local it is working fine. when i am trying to call that perticular dll in live, it shows an error of "Unable to load DLL 'Geospot.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
and
Unable to load DLL 'Geospot.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
i am using visual studio 2005. and all configurations are fine.

can anybody solve my problem?
thanking you,

Comment: You need to make sure that `geospot.dll` is available to the application. Put it in the same folder, put it in a folder in the DLL search paths, register it in the GAC etc...

Comment: ok i am tried. in that way also i got same error.